# Add class to ancestor element based on existence of element in the hierarchy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sample code below

```
<li class="treeview">
 <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>Multilevel</span>
 <span class="pull-right-container">
 <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
 </span>
 </a>
 <ul class="treeview-menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link in level 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link in level 2</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

If one of the `li` has a class `active` how can I also add a class `active` on the parent `li` or this part

`<li class="treeview">`

Comment: Just to clarify are you using a js to put some class name to the elements?

Comment: yes sir sorry, already edited

Comment: Please, also add the codes of the js/jquery

Comment: in the first palce, how do you add `active` to li?

Comment: @Francisaskquestion i dont have code for now

Comment: @NidhinJoseph just added it manualy but soon it will be dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to select any `li.active` outside of the `.treeview` tree hierarchy:

```
$('.treeview li.active').closest('.treeview').addClass('active');
```

Comment: just a question. In case i have multiple `<li class="treeview">` because it will be by group with submenus. If i have an active `li` does all `<li class="treeview">` will be added or the nearest parent of the selected?

Comment: @NardongBagsik yes

Comment: My target here is when I select a `<li>` its group `li` will the only added with class active not all with class `treeview`

Comment: @NardongBagsik yes, what you are saying is correct if there are multiple `treeview` hierarchies and you make an `li` within one of them active, only the parent `treeview` of the active `li` will be made `active`

Comment: ahhhh ok i get it. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 2):

If you need the entire `treeview` ancestry of an active `<li>` to have the class `.active`, you can use jQuery's `:has`:

```
$('.treeview:has(li.active)').addClass('active');
```

```js
$('.treeview:has(li.active)').addClass('active');
```

```css
.active::before {content: 'Active - '}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="treeview">1
    <ul>
      <li class="treeview">2
        <ul>
          <li class="treeview">3
            <ul>
              <li class="active">4</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="treeview">1
    <ul>
      <li class="treeview">2
        <ul>
          <li class="treeview">3
            <ul>
              <li>4</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="treeview">1
    <ul>
      <li class="treeview">2
        <ul>
          <li class="treeview">3
            <ul>
              <li>4</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you need only the immediately closest `treeview`, you can use `.closest()`:

```
$('.treeview li.active').closest(".treeview").addClass('active');
```

```js
$('.treeview li.active').closest(".treeview").addClass('active');
```

```css
.active::before {content: 'Active - '}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="treeview">1
    <ul>
      <li class="treeview">2
        <ul>
          <li class="treeview">3
            <ul>
              <li class="active">4 (Active)</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="treeview">1
    <ul>
      <li class="treeview">2
        <ul>
          <li class="treeview">3
            <ul>
              <li>4</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="treeview">1
    <ul>
      <li class="treeview">2
        <ul>
          <li class="treeview">3
            <ul>
              <li>4</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery to achieve this. Please find the snippet below.

```js
$('.treeview-menu li').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(this).closest('li.treeview').addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.active>a {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="treeview">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>Multilevel</span>
 <span class="pull-right-container">
 <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
 </span>
 </a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
      <li class=""><a href="#">Link in level 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link in level 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```